# Failed to construct transformer: DuplicateError: Duplicated files or mocks. Please check the console for more info

Tags: react-native, aws-amplify

can someone help me with this duplicated error in react native

warn No apps connected. Sending "devMenu" to all React Native apps failed. Make sure your app is running in the simulator or on a phone connected via USB.
info Opening developer menu...

jest-haste-map: Haste module naming collision: CreatePaymentIntent
The following files share their name; please adjust your hasteImpl:
* \amplify#current-cloud-backend\function\CreatePaymentIntent\src\package.json
* \amplify\backend\function\CreatePaymentIntent\src\package.json

Failed to construct transformer:  DuplicateError: Duplicated files or mocks. Please check the console for more info
at setModule (G:\IT\Portfolio\Amazon\AmazonClone\node_modules\jest-haste-map\build\index.js:543:17)
at workerReply (G:\IT\Portfolio\Amazon\AmazonClone\node_modules\jest-haste-map\build\index.js:614:9)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
at async Promise.all (index 497)
at async G:\IT\Portfolio\Amazon\AmazonClone\node_modules\jest-haste-map\build\index.js:426:22 {
mockPath1: 'amplify\#current-cloud-backend\function\CreatePaymentIntent\src\package.json',
mockPath2: 'amplify\backend\function\CreatePaymentIntent\src\package.json'
}
info Launching Dev Tools...
Error: Duplicated files or mocks. Please check the console for more info
at setModule (G:\IT\Portfolio\Amazon\AmazonClone\node_modules\jest-haste-map\build\index.js:543:17)
at workerReply (G:\IT\Portfolio\Amazon\AmazonClone\node_modules\jest-haste-map\build\index.js:614:9)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
at async Promise.all (index 497)
at async G:\IT\Portfolio\Amazon\AmazonClone\node_modules\jest-haste-map\build\index.js:426:22